# Jenkins git plugin add strange chars in password

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm use Jenkins 2.164.3 and trying to clone a repository with Git Plugin I get the error " authentication failed", because for some reason git plugin add "%24" in front of my password read from password parameter.

I read here:
[enter link description here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20533?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true)

It was an old bug of 5 years ago of git plugin, but now should be solved!

Could you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: That link seems to suggest that the `$` sign in a password is being percent-encoded, not that %24 is being added at the front. It sounds like your problem is different.

Comment: Password Is read as password parameter, no $ are present in password. I suppose the $ is from expanding environment variable associated to password.